# PL/SQL triggers with two existing tables and one empty table

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers, runtime-error

I am trying to write a trigger that will insert into an empty table the employeeID, employeeName, old department, new department and effective date from two already existing tables employee and department. I have to retrieve that department name from the department table. I got a "bad bind variable" error from oracle and I don't know what I have to fix:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER emp_dept_change_trg
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON EMPLOYEE
   FOR EACH ROW

   DECLARE
   v_dept DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENT_NAME%TYPE;

   BEGIN

    SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME
         INTO v_dept
         FROM DEPARTMENT
         WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = :NEW.DEPARTMENT_ID;

   IF INSERTING THEN
         INSERT INTO emp_dept_change
         VALUES(:NEW.EMPLOYEE_ID, :NEW.EMPLOYEE_NAME, '[New Hire]',:NEW.DEPARTMENT_NAME ,SYSDATE);

   ELSIF UPDATING THEN

  IF :OLD.DEPARTMENT_ID != :NEW.DEPARTMENT_ID THEN
  INSERT INTO emp_dept_change
  VALUES(:OLD.EMPLOYEE_ID, :OLD.EMPLOYEE_NAME, :OLD.DEPARTMENT_NAME, :NEW.DEPARTMENT_NAME ,SYSDATE);    


   END IF;      
   END IF;
   END;
```

I am following logical steps as well:

Write a trigger emp_dept_change_trg that monitors the employee table as follows.

When a row (record) is inserted into the employee table, the trigger automatically inserts a row (record) into the emp_dept_change table in any situations.

The OLD_DEPARTMENT_NAME is always '[New Hire]'.

Find the new department name from the department table based on the new department_id.

If the new department_id is NULL, the NEW_DEPARTMENT_NAME will be '[-----]'.

When an employee changes his/her department (the old department_id is not equal to the new department_id), the trigger automatically inserts a row (record) into the emp_dept_change table. (If both the old department_id and new department_id are NULL (from NULL department to NULL department), the trigger does not insert a row (record) into the emp_dept_change table.)

Find the old department name from the department table based on the old department_id.

If the old department_id is NULL, the OLD_DEPARTMENT_NAME will be '[-----]'.

Find the new department name from the department table based on the new department_id.

If the new department_id is NULL, the NEW_DEPARTMENT_NAME will be '[-----]'.

The SYSDATE can be used in the EFFECTIVE_DATE column.

You can assume that the insert/update statements do not violate the integrity constraints between the department and employee tables.

No temporary table/view/procedure/function is allowed in your trigger.

You can only use the department, employee, and emp_dept_change tables in your trigger.

Comment: Well, what line is the error on??  Please show the complete error message and stack trace.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It seems like I should have a variable for the department name that I want to insert into the employee table

Comment: Sounds like homework...